# Find conditional density $f\left(x_1,\cdots,x_n\mid x_{(n)}\right)$

Tags: probability

Assume $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are iid random variables from a uniform distribution on $(-a,a)$. Let $X_{(n)}$ be the $\max_{i=1,\cdots,n} X_i$. How do I find the conditional density
$$f\left(x_1,\cdots,x_n\mid x_{(n)}\right)\,?$$

Ultimately I would like to compute something like
$$\mathbb{P}\left\{ \left(X_1,\cdots,X_n\right)\in A \mid X_{(n)} = c\right\}$$

I know how to find density for $X_{(n)}$, but I don't know how to find density for $\left(X_1,\cdots,X_n, X_{(n)}\right)$. The problem is that $X_{(n)}$ is not independent from the rest.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that $X_{(n)}$ is not independent from the rest.

That's not a problem.  It simply asserts that the density is zero unless at least one of the samples equals the largest order statistic, and further the other samples may not exceed it (since it is the largest).   That defines the conditional function's support.

$f(x_1,\ldots x_n\mid x_{(n)}) =\begin{cases} ?/? &:& (\exists^{=k} j\in\Bbb N{\cap}[1;n]: x_j=x_{(n)}), (\forall j\in\Bbb N{\cap}[1;n]: x_j\leq x_n)\\0 &:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

$~$

---

$\exists^{=k}$ is the counting existential quantifier: "there exists exactly $k$"